# How to assign Values to a Get Function

Tags: java

The below program is to set up Get Functions and then retrieve the totals at the bottom to enter into those Get functions. The get functions will help get the total for concert sales. I have set up my get functions, and believe they are correct. My questions are that I dont know how to send the totals at the bottom to the get functions. and then take those totals and print them as well send them to the computeTotalSales function. then of course print out the total sales. Are my get functions set up incorrectly. Or am I not calling them right? HELP!

```
public class QuestionHelp {

public class ConcertSales{
private int numberOfSeatTypesA;
private int numberOfSeatTypesB;

public double totalSales;
public double pricePerSeatA;
public double pricePerSeatB;


public int getNumberOfSeatTypesA()
{
   return numberOfSeatTypesA;
}

public int getNumberOfSeatTypesB()
{
   return numberOfSeatTypesB;    
}


public double getPricePerSeatA()
{
   return pricePerSeatA;
}

public double getPricePerSeatB()
{
   return pricePerSeatB;
}



public double computeTotalSales()
{
   return totalSales = numberOfSeatTypesA*pricePerSeatA +
                       numberOfSeatTypesB*pricePerSeatB; 
}
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int numberOfSeatTypesA = 30;
   int numberOfSeatTypesB = 44;

   double pricePerSeatA = 120.99;
   double pricePerSeatB = 90.77;

}

}
```

Comment: This isn't JavaScript

Comment: i'm sorry jdphenix, i was unsure.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html This will help

Answer (score 0):

The four variables within your main method that you assign values to are completely different from the public and private class variables you created for the ConcertSales class. To use those in your main method, you would have to create an instance of the ConcertSales class

```
ConcertSales concertSales = new ConcertSales;
```

and then you can print out the values using the get methods that you created like this:

```
System.out.println(concertSales.getPricePerSeatA());
```

The problem is, the private variables of the class will likely be null because you don't have any methods to **set** their values.

Public variables however you'll be able to access using the dot operator:

```
System.out.println("Total sales were: " + concertSales.totalSales);
```

I understand you're a beginner (your name is JavaBeginner, afterall), but I would suggest reading up more on Java and perhaps looking into a beginner level Java tutorial to improve.

Comment: thanks all. my teacher also directed me into some good solutions